# How to parse a list of list of spring properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-el

I have this Spring boot application.properties

```
list1=valueA,valueB
list2=valueC
list3=valueD,valueE

topics=list1,list2,list3
```

What I'm trying to do is to use in the `topics` element of `@KafkaListener` annotation the values of the values of topics property

Using the expression

```
@KafkaListener(topics={"#{'${topics}'.split(',')}"})
```

I get `list1`,`list2`,`list3` as separated string

How can I loop on this list in order to get `valueA`,`valueB`,`valueC`,`valueD`,`valueE`?

**Edit**: I must parse `topics` properties in order that @KafkaListener registers for consuming message from topics `valueA`,`valueB`,`valueC`, etc.

I read that is possible call a method in this way:

```
@KafkaListener(topics="#parse(${topics})")
```

So, I wrote this method:

```
public String[] parse(String s) {
   ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

   return Arrays.stream(s.split(",").map(key -> (String)(parser.parse(key).getValue())).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

But the `parse` method is not invoked

So, I tried directly to do this into annotations
in this way:

```
@KafkaListener(topics="#{Arrays.stream('${topics}'.split(',')).map(key->${key}).toArray(String[]::new)}")
```

But also this solution give me errors.

**Edit 2:**

Modifying in this way the method is invoked

```
@KafkaListener(topics="parse()")

@Bean
    public String[] parse(String s) {
       ...
    }
```

The problems is how to get "topics" props inside the method

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; `topics` takes a `String[]`.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to to this: `@KafkaListener(topics="#{parse($(topics))}")`. The method parse returns `Arrays.stream(s.split(",")).map(p -> "${p}").toArray(String[]::new);`.
I know that `${p}` has no sense in map, but the method is however not invoked.

Comment: It's still not clear; edit the question to show exactly what you are trying to do, and what the problem is.

Comment: I edited the question. I Hope is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke arbitrary methods like that; you need to reference a bean `@someBean.parse(...)`; using `#parse` requires registering a static method as a function.

However, this works for me and is much simpler:

```
list1=valueA,valueB
list2=valueC
list3=valueD,valueE

topics=${list1},${list2},${list3}
```

and

```
@KafkaListener(id = "so64390079", topics = "#{'${topics}'.split(',')}")
```

**EDIT**

If you can't use placeholders in `topics`, this works...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64390079Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64390079Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so64390079", topics = "#{@parser.parse('${topics}')}")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}

@Component
class Parser implements EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment environmment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environmment = environment;
    }

    public String[] parse(String[] topics) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String topic : topics) {
            sb.append(this.environmment.getProperty(topic));
            sb.append(',');
        }
        return StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 1));
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought to do this, but requirements are that topics properties must be in `topics=list1,list2,list3` format.

Comment: Seems to work, but It's invoked two times, and the second times give a StringIndexOutOfBoundException because topics params is empty. Why is invoked two times?

Comment: I have no idea; it's only called once in my test app; try setting a breakpoint to see if it gives any clues. You can always add code to protect against that. (`if (sb.length() > 0`).

Comment: Checking in debug mode, first time I get the correct output but second time I get the error. Very strange.